# GroupBy doesnt work on Readonly Collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

```cs
currentUsers.GroupBy(user => user.ID)
            .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()
            .AsEnumerable());
```

Tried to find duplicates by using `GroupBy` on the readonly collection but it throws null reference exception:

> Object not set to an instance of the object

Tried converting the readonly collection to list , but it still throws the same exception.The linq query works fine in immediate window in Visual Studio 2017 but fails during runtime and debugging. Could someone please help?

Comment: What is `null` in this code, is it `currentUsers`, or anything thats inside any of the other statements? - Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186

Comment: Where does the data of _currentUsers_ come from? Maybe it's null

Answer (score 0):

`currentUsers` likely contains a `null` value.

Try:

```
currentUsers
        .Where(user => user != null)
        .GroupBy(user => user.ID)
        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()
        .AsEnumerable());
```

As a side note: if you're using a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`, consider using `ToLookup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If *currentUsers* is not null, most probably it contains a null reference itself during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var result = currentUsers?.GroupBy(cu => cu?.ID)
                          .Select(g => new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
                          .Where(g => g.Count > 1)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Then check if result is null